# Keycloak: ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Tags: keycloak

I'm learning Keycloak and I have the following problem.

I have a Java EE application protected through Keycloak (main-app). After logging into keycloak, it accesses another application (app-example, also protected by keycloak) that performs a check and depending on the result returns to main-app or shows an error.

The problem is that app-example redirects to keycloak and keycloak redirects back to app-example. At the end, I get the error: 400 bad request.

In front of keycloak I have an Apache server that acts as a proxy and all connections are via SSL.

First call:

```
Request URL: https://localhost/app-example
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 302 Found
Remote Address: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 0
Date: Mon, 17 Dec 2018 14:09:07 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=96
Location: https://localhost/auth/realms/my-realm/protocol/openid-connect/auth?response_type=code&client_id=appexample&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fapp-example%2F&state=e327185a-6306-4124-b384-215954f51bb7&login=true&scope=openid
Server: Apache/2.4.10 (Debian) mod_jk/1.2.37 OpenSSL/1.0.1t
Set-Cookie: OAuth_Token_Request_State=e327185a-6306-4124-b384-215954f51bb7; Version=1; Secure; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=AxzD3hq5sfv-SJdbSa7HDLJe1lBWC1ExBoy86TdR; path=/app-example
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15768000
X-Powered-By: Undertow/1
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: es-ES,es;q=0.9
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: OAuth_Token_Request_State=6f634ef2-cc69-4cb8-bdaa-2d69929b26a8; JSESSIONID=BVzI9MiQB6FYFIUDLyK2dQU_o6OPSCyZB9NQDfXV
Host: localhost
Pragma: no-cache
Referer: https://localhost/main-app/
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.110 Safari/537.36
```

Second call:

```
Request URL: https://localhost/auth/realms/my-realm/protocol/openid-connect/auth?response_type=code&client_id=app-example&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fapp-example%2F&state=e327185a-6306-4124-b384-215954f51bb7&login=true&scope=openid
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 302 Found
Remote Address: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
Cache-Control: no-store, must-revalidate, max-age=0
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 0
Date: Mon, 17 Dec 2018 14:09:08 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=10
Location: https://localhost/app-example/?state=e327185a-6306-4124-b384-215954f51bb7&session_state=39fc0c37-e60d-42e7-876a-97501753bd6a&code=eyJhbGciOiJkaXIiLCJlbmMiOiJBMTI4Q0JDLUhTMjU2In0..pDbVJYc-fWIWXhsycldqHA.4nZs2gTZZyNhHRDDF3vjd99vCmM6INRMGk8T-Svcc6U1nxtFu7am_Ck2oTNZKYs0_zRHzgUkU4mzmdfRrTRoN64b4uosAVvZKSx_UDhaOERbaLk4p1wqjAUswc2N-48Vb92XBPr-ihET5WF3mzcGeb2TK6k1_GjaBLdEz4BlO8cYVisp35HNIq1APR7GPh9UbCrJaspLegxrvY5_lM9GPsF3NwWorWFE8G3BeUSQeqF7CwTY4YXJnTPkarbwaYX9.-uqvbrqkLz2JLLjeBl4n3g
P3P: CP="This is not a P3P policy!"
Referrer-Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
Server: Apache
Set-Cookie: AUTH_SESSION_ID=39fc0c37-e60d-42e7-876a-97501753bd6a.public:server-public-1; Version=1; Path=/auth/realms/my-realm/; Secure; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: KC_RESTART=eyJhb....9Y3M; Version=1; Path=/auth/realms/my-realm/; Secure; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: KEYCLOAK_SESSION=my-realm/f24b7ee7-b32e-4e93-821f-cfbf4708acf4/39fc0c37-e60d-42e7-876a-97501753bd6a; Version=1; Expires=Tue, 18-Dec-2018 00:09:08 GMT; Max-Age=36000; Path=/auth/realms/my-realm/; Secure
Set-Cookie: KEYCLOAK_REMEMBER_ME=; Version=1; Comment=Expiring cookie; Expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:10 GMT; Max-Age=0; Path=/auth/realms/my-realm/; Secure; HttpOnly
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15768000
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: es-ES,es;q=0.9
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: KEYCLOAK_LOCALE=es; AUTH_SESSION_ID=39fc0c37-e60d-42e7-876a-97501753bd6a.public:server-public-1; KEYCLOAK_SESSION=my-realm/f24b7ee7-b32e-4e93-821f-cfbf4708acf4/39fc0c37-e60d-42e7-876a-97501753bd6a; KEYCLOAK_IDENTITY=eyJhb.....Qgs
Host: localhost
Pragma: no-cache
Referer: https://localhost/main-app/
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.110 Safari/537.36
response_type: code
client_id: appexample
redirect_uri: https://localhost/app-example/
state: e327185a-6306-4124-b384-215954f51bb7
login: true
scope: openid
scope: openid
```

In the log I observe:

```
    ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-73) UT005023: Exception handling request to /main-app/launcher.jsp: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: UT000139: Exchange already complete
```

I checked that the json file I got from keycloak and integrated into the application is correct. What's the problem?

cheers

Comment: You might have to configure proxy as described at https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_installation/index.html#_proxymappings

Now when I have a second thought, what's the name of your Realm? 
There's a bug (according to me, but not by their teamlead) with spaces in the Realm name. It took me quite some debugging time to find it out, which was leading exactly to too many redirects error.

Comment: ... and this is the Jira I created some time ago https://issues.jboss.org/browse/KEYCLOAK-7844

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried clearing your cookies?

In case you're using chrome:
https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/6098869?visit_id=637347644493186330-3872337140&p=rl_error&hl=en-GB&rd=1#redirect

Also using private window will likely help. In my case this was caused by running multiple keycloak instances on localhost over time, which got their cookies mixed up.

Answer (score 0):

Carefully check `Frontend URL` setting in Realm Settings