# Keycloak high availability cluster on Kubernetes ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS when login to admin console

Tags: keycloak, high-availability, dev-to-production

I'm trying to deploy a high availability Keycloak cluster on AWS EKS.

I've tried to follow the [Configuring Keycloak for production](https://www.keycloak.org/server/configuration-production) instructions, but I find it pretty fuzzy.

Anyhow, I have:

- EKS cluster
- ALB as a reverse proxy for terminating SSL
- Custom hostname
- Inifinispan cache using Kubernetes as `CACHE_STACK`

I can access the service using https and everything works as I would expect using 1 node, but when I change replicas to 2 I get `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` when I login to the admin console.

Here's my configuration:

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM --platform=linux/arm64 quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:18.0.0 as builder

ENV KC_HEALTH_ENABLED=true
ENV KC_METRICS_ENABLED=true
ENV KC_FEATURES=token-exchange
ENV KC_DB=postgres
ENV KC_CACHE_STACK=kubernetes
## Install custom providers
COPY auth-identione-extension/target/auth-identione-extension-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar /opt/keycloak/providers
RUN /opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh build

FROM --platform=linux/arm64 quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:18.0.0
COPY --from=builder /opt/keycloak/ /opt/keycloak/

ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh"]
```

**statefulset.yaml**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  namespace: default
  name: keycloak-deployment
spec:
  serviceName: keycloak-service
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: keycloak-app
  replicas: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/name: keycloak-app
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: {myKeycloakImage}
          name: keycloak-app
          args: ["-Djgroups.dns.query=keycloak-service", "start"]
          env:
            - name: KC_HOSTNAME
              value: "auth.mydomain.com"
            - name: KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT_HTTPS
              value: "false"
            - name: KC_PROXY
              value: "edge"
            - name: KC_DB_URL
              value: {db-url}
            - name: KC_DB_USERNAME
              value: {db-username}
            - name: KC_DB_PASSWORD
              value: {db-password}
          resources:
            requests:
              memory: "512Mi"
              cpu: "500m"
            limits:
              memory: "1024Mi"
              cpu: "1000m"
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 8080
```

**service.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  namespace: default
  name: keycloak-service
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 8180
      targetPort: 8080
      protocol: TCP
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: keycloak-app
```

**ingress.yaml**

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  namespace: default
  name: keycloak-service-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type: ip
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/listen-ports: '[{"HTTP": 80}, {"HTTPS":443}]'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/certificate-arn: {certificateArn}
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: '443'
spec:
  rules:
    - host: auth.mydomain.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /*
            backend:
              serviceName: keycloak-service
              servicePort: 8180
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be much easier if you use an existing helm chart : https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami

Comment: Ok, I haven't used helm before, can I use my own Keycloak image?
The reason is that I need to add my custom authentication provider to the image.

Comment: Yes you can specify your own image https://github.com/bitnami/charts/blob/master/bitnami/keycloak/values.yaml#L76

Comment: Turns out it's not so easy to get a keycloak running with production settings using bitnami either...

Answer (score 0):

You have misconfigured the cache, hence those two replicas do not communicate with themselves. See [Keycloak: ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53821587/keycloak-err-too-many-redirects) for similar discussion.

The "-Djgroups.dns.query" should point to headless service of keycloak and it should be set as a part of JAVA_OPTS_APPEND environment variable for keycloak.

Reference: https://www.keycloak.org/server/caching